# Format a number with an exponent in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a number which is displaying as follows:

```
1.0333333333333335e-9
```

I'd like to limit the number of digits that's shown, so it looks more like:

```
1.03e-9
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`numObj.toExponential(fractionDigits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) has it built in

> *fractionDigits*
>
> An integer specifying the number of digits after the decimal point.
>   Defaults to as many digits as necessary to specify the number.